# custom cursor adapter not showing

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I got a cursor from an return method like this

```
Cursor result = dc.show(comp);
```

when i read the values using

```
Log.i("cursor value1",result.getString(0));
```

I am getting the value of it correctly
But my adapter doesnt seem to work

```
Cursor result = dc.showCompanyAndAdvertisee(comp);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, result);
l.setAdapter(adapter);


class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
LayoutInflater inflater;
Cursor c;

public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);        

}



@Override   
public void bindView(View view, Context arg1, Cursor c)    {
    TextView tv0 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.singletextView1);

TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.singletextView2);

TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.singletextView3); 
    tv0.setText(c.getString(0));
    tv1.setText(c.getString(1));
    tv2.setText(c.getString(2));    }

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)    {
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single,parent,false);
    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: any reason not to using a SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: no specific reason...but can u tell me the error in this?

Comment: seems ok, just try SCA, its much more simple

Comment: can u tell me how to fill the constructor of SCA for this cursor?

Comment: see http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_example_entry, cursor, columns, to,flags);In this constructor can u tell me wat the columns will be according to my code?

Comment: its for example "name", "age" if you query your db as select name, age from table ...